# What are best practices for maintaining state for Ajax for an MVC web application

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on an asp.net mvc application. But this question is applicable to other mvc style web applications as well. What's the best practice or pattern for maintaining state for a page with the following functionality:

1. User loads Create Group page
2. In the same page, there is a list for Group Members
3. User is able to add and delete group members and is able to select a group member and update its details. All actions are not yet submitted to the server and do not make any database change.
4. User clicks save button to save all changes including Group details, addition, deletion and updates to group members. Changes are submitted to the server all at once via ajax.

What I have in mind are the following:

1. Maintain the group and members list using javascript and submit the group and group members via ajax in one go.
2. Maintain the group and members in server session. that means as new members are added or removed to the list, the session data is updated via ajax. When the user clicks save. Whatever is in memory is persisted to the database.
3. Both options above can have browser and server side validations

Any advice on the approach?

Comment: Well, I would say both 1 and 2 are acceptable. I would prefer the first one cause I think it will be easier to implement as you don't have to handle the "temporary state" on server, but it has some flaws : if a problem occurs on the user's computer, all changes will be lost. And also, in case of concurrent access, you may have some trouble if different users update the same item. You should definitely think of a "record locking" pattern if that's a concern for you

Comment: @Bartdude We will be implementing optimistic locking so tough lock on whoever updates later. Thus behavior is acceptable to the users.